# Efficient way to compute p^q (exponentiation), where q is an integer

Tags: c++, math, exponentiation

What is an efficient way to compute p<sup>q</sup>, where q is an integer?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Exponentiation by squaring](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) uses only O(lg *q*) multiplications.

```
template <typename T>
T expt(T p, unsigned q)
{
    T r(1);

    while (q != 0) {
        if (q % 2 == 1) {    // q is odd
            r *= p;
            q--;
        }
        p *= p;
        q /= 2;
    }

    return r;
}
```

This should work on any [monoid](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Monoid) (`T`, `operator*`) where a `T` constructed from `1` is the identity element. That includes all numeric types.

Extending this to `signed q` is easy: just divide one by the result of the above for the absolute value of `q` (but as usual, be careful when computing the absolute value).

Comment: I -1d this because it is not a complete answer; exponentiation by squaring is a good algorithm, but there are other concerns as well.

Comment: @Joe: the OP was asking for a suggestion, not a complete solution or a proof of correctness.

Comment: Generally, I assume someone asking a question wants a complete solution. Rarely are questions asked expecting half-answers.

Comment: @Joe: I posted a link to the Wikipedia page, which covers most of what you need to know to implement this algorithm. I'm not going to explain implementation details like recursion-versus-iteration every time; I assume those are well-known enough. If the OP has a problem with this answer, they can post a comment asking for further clarification.

Comment: When one is discussing issues of efficiency, I don't see recursion-versus-iteration as an implementation detail, but rather a core question to be addressed, as the choice impacts efficiency.

Comment: @Joe: if the OP had the naive pseudo-linear time loop algorithm in mind, then this is enough of an improvement to make recursion-vs.-iteration a detail.

Comment: And if the OP did not, then it is not. That's why it's important to provide a complete answer.

Comment: Do downvotes really hurt that much? Is 98 rep out of a three word Wikipedia link really so little you must be upset, or upset on someone else's behalf?

Comment: @Joe: I imagine it's the principle of the thing. Still, I agree with you. :)

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig:  The usual standard for votes (as revealed by hovering on the voting arrows) is "is this answer useful", not "is this answer as complete as it is possible to be".  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers

Comment: @wnoise: I'm not a usual voter. Nor do I think "revenge upvoting" a good pattern.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: I agree that compensatory upvoting should be avoided, and I don't do it.   An upvote gives much more karma than is taken away by a downvote.  However, many people do this, so pushing an accurate, but incomplete reply below zero will usually provoke an upvote to zero.  So that should also be avoided...

Comment: This is currently at +17 - most garnered when it was a 3 word Wikipedia link - and accepted. That's horrible. In lieu of SO actually allowing me to rate answers, I have to vote how I feel will promote the best answer. This is not the best answer, so I have to downvote it.

Comment: To be pedantically precise, exponentiation by squaring is **not** O(lg q), since that ignores the complexity of the multiplications.  If you restrict yourself to machine-word multiplications, then you also restrict the exponent to a fixed range of exponents, in which case the complexity is just O(1).

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that `^` means exponentiation and that `q` is runtime variable, use `std::pow(double, int)`.

EDIT: For completeness due to the comments on this answer: I asked the question [Why was std::pow(double, int) removed from C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627030) about the missing function and in fact `pow(double, int)` wasn't removed in C++0x, just the language was changed. However, it appears that libraries may not actually optimize it due to result accuracy concerns.

Even given that I would *still* use `pow` until measurement showed me that it needed to be optimized.

Comment: And assuming p can be coerced to a double.

Comment: @downvoter: What's the problem with this solution? The standard library is likely to have a highly optimized `pow` function when runtime variability is needed.

Comment: Actually, I just checked my C++0x draft, and std::pow(double,int) is not defined. std::pow(double,double) and std::pow(float,float), and some more complex overloads, are. I think that means 1) any library offering std::pow(double,int) is non-standard, and 2) if they do special-case integer-valued doubles at runtime, that would be sigificant overhead. So although I was not the downvoter, I am also going to -1 this.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig I spotted it in C++98 26.5/6 and assumed they wouldn't remove functionality in 0x. Did they remove it in C++0x (I don't have a handy copy of that standard)?

Comment: @Mark B: I actually cannot find a C++98 PDF on Google quickly, but in my C++0x PDF, the only mention of pow on primitive types is via C99 transclusion in 26.8, and it only defines pow for float,float, double,double, and long double,long double.

Comment: (Obviously in practice I would not think twice about using std::pow when available, but if the goal is a fast power function with no restrictions on the type of p - rather than the goal being some other computation which requires a power function but most likely contains some lower-hanging fruit - I don't think it's an acceptable answer. On the other hand, I think Stepanov's exercise in describing it is invaluable, even though I use std::pow.)

Comment: @MarkB: Hard to have a copy of something that doesn't exist. :)

Comment: @Mark, your solution is correct given the assumption that std library always implements the pow in the most efficient way. But here, I am more interested in how to do this implementation rather than how to use it. -- thank you

Answer (score 9):

I assume by ^ you mean power function, and not bitwise xor.

The development of an efficient power function for *any type of p and any positive integral q* is the subject of [an entire section, 3.2, in Stepanov's and McJones's book *Elements of Programming*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032163537X). The language in the book is not C++, but is very easily translated into C++.

It covers several optimizations, including exponentiation by squaring, conversion to tail recursion then iteration, and accumulation-variable elimination, and relates the optimizations to the notions of type regularity and associative operations to prove it works for all such types.

Comment: Interesting read: https://books.google.com/books?id=tjOlkl7ecVQC&lpg=PA33&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false