# C++11 in conjunction with OpenMP gives slower executable

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

I am trying to learn OpenMP and want to study speed-up using OpenMP. For this purpose, I have written the following small program:

```C++
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    static const unsigned int testDataSize = 1 << 28;

    std::vector<double> a (testDataSize), b (testDataSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < testDataSize; ++i) {
        a [i] = static_cast<double> (23 ^ i) / 1000.0;
    }
    b.resize(testDataSize);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < testDataSize; ++i) {
        b [i] = std::pow(a[i], 3) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 5) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 7) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 9) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 11) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 13) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 15) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 17) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 19) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
        b [i] += std::pow(a[i], 21) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above code either with or without the -std=c++11 directive. What I notice is that when I am using the -std=c++11 directive, my code runs about 8 times slower as without using this. I am using -O3 and gcc version 4.9.2 on a Linux Debian system. Furthermore, when I compare the execution times without using OpenMP, I do note a speed difference. Thus, it looks to me that there is a problem with the -std=c++11 and not with OpenMP.

In detail, I obtain the following execution times (a measured using the Linux `time` command)

**Compilation with OpenMP and -std=c++11:** 35.262s

**Compilation only with OpenMP:** 5.875s

**Compilation with only -std=c++11:** 2m12

**Compilation without OpenMP and -std=c++11:** 23.757s

What is the reason that the execution time is much slower when using -std=c++11?

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

---

I have tagged what, in my humble opinion, is the best answer. In follow-up of oLen's answer, I have made my own pow(double, int) function as given below:

```
double my_pow(double base, int exp) {
    double result = 1.0;

    while (exp) {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am not sure whether this is the most efficient way to calculate the integer power of some base number, but using this function I get exactly the same results in terms of computational efficiency when compiling with or without std=c++11 fully in line with oLen's answer.

Comment: Try throwing it at godbot and comparing generated assembly?

Comment: What is your question?  "Why is c++11 so much slower?".  What options are you using?  What does the assembly look like?

Comment: *<pedantic>This is a program, not a script.</pedantic>*

Comment: @erip: Indeed; thanks for the correction. I have changed script into program in the question above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that the version without -std=c++11 uses `std::pow(double,int)`, which is apparently not available in C++11, and faster than `std::pow(double,double)`. If you replace your integers (3, 5, etc.) by doubles (3.0, 5.0, etc.), you will get the same speed.

**EDIT:**
Here are my timings with g++ version 4.8.4:
**Original version:**
-O3 -fopenmp : **10.678 s**
-O3 -fopenmp -std=c++11 : **36.994 s**
**Adding ".0" after the integers:**
-O3 -fopenmp : **36.679 s**
-O3 -fopenmp -std=c++11 : **36.938 s**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I updated the answer with the timings I got

Comment: Can you suggest a version that gives the lower figure for both compile modes?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: For this particular code, it's trivially easy to get rid of the calls to `pow` entirely.  `accum += power; power *= a[i] * a[i];`

Comment: @BenVoigt: I am offering the answer author the opportunity to expand their answer to provide the best approach. That may be the best approach. But it's for the OP in the answer, not for me in the comments.

Comment: @oLen: Thanks a lot for the clear answer! I never expected it to be such a 'silly' thing like that C++11 does not have a pow(double, int) version...

Comment: I cannot think of a solution to get the faster version with C++11. There is a small discussion about that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627030/why-was-stdpowdouble-int-removed-from-c11 but there doesn't seem to be a solution

Comment: `double(*fptr)(double, int) = std::pow; fptr(3.14,2);`?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the function overload selection issue @oLen pointed out, you have false sharing, which is hurting parallelism.  Don't access the array member in every statement, it is in memory directly adjacent to elements being modified in other threads, which causes thrashing of the cache coherency algorithm.  Instead accumulate results in a temporary and only write the result array once:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testDataSize; ++i) {
    double accum = std::pow(a[i], 3) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 5) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 7) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 9) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 11) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 13) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 15) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 17) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 19) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 21) * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
    b[i] = accum;
}
```

For that matter, calling `std::exp(-a[i] * a[i])` only once and saving the result should help even the single-threaded case, since it's very difficult for the compiler to prove this common subexpression can be optimized.  And best of all, factor that out of the entire calculation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testDataSize; ++i) {
    double accum = std::pow(a[i], 3);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 5);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 7);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 9);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 11);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 13);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 15);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 17);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 19);
    accum += std::pow(a[i], 21);
    b[i] = accum * std::exp(-a[i] * a[i]);
}
```

Comment: I was about to mention storing `a[i]` as well. Nice answer.

Comment: @erip: `a[i]` is only being read, not written, so the false sharing doesn't cause problems (all cores can have the cache line in state `S` -- shared, read-only)

Comment: Very helpful suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In top of excellent answer by @oLen, quick check shows that in previous libstdc++ `pow(double, int)` was just a thunk to `__builtin_powi (double, int)`, which computes power via multiplication. It was found that in general it is impossible to produce the same result for `pow(double, int)` and `pow(double, double(int))`, thus to follow standard implementation in c++11 library was changed to use `pow(double, double)` and if second argument is an int there would be cast involved. Documentation for GCC was changed as well, and it is now stated that

```
— Built-in Function: double __builtin_powi (double, int)
    Returns the first argument raised to the power of the second. Unlike the pow function no guarantees about precision and rounding are made.
```

Link: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html