# Fast way to compute n times 10 raised to the power of minus m

Tags: c++, math, pow

I want to compute 10 raised to the power minus `m`. In addition to use the math function `pow(10, -m)`, is there any fast and efficient way to do that?

What I ask such a simple question to the c++ gurus from SO is that, as you know, just like base 2, 10 is also a special base. If some value `n` times the 10's power minus `m`, it is equivalent to move n's decimal point to the left m times. I think it must be a fast and efficient way to cope with.

Comment: Is m an integer ? Is it always positive ? What is its maximum value ? Unless you list constraints such as this then you won't get an optimal solution.

Comment: As some of the answers remarked, 9+1 is _not_ a special base, unless you happen to be a human being who, coincidentally, turns out to have that number of fingers. But your computer doesn't, so avoid base 10. It's only considerable to use it when dealing with data where somebody will actually read the numbers, but that's only interesting when there are no more than, like, 100 of them - and for such small amounts, performance doesn't really matter at all.

Comment: Do you need an integral solution or a floating-point one? Are `n` or `m` compile-time constants?

Answer (score 5):

For floating point m, so long as your standard library implementation is well written, then `pow` will be efficient.

If m is an integer, and you hinted that it is, then you could use an array of pre calculated values.

You should only be worrying about this kind of thing if that routine is a bottleneck in your code. That is if the calls to that routine take a significant proportion of the total running time.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to write *deficient*?

Comment: @space predictive keyboard on my phone made that decision thanks!

Comment: Thank you for quick response. pow can make do for desktop PCs.

Answer (score 4):

Ten is not a special value on a binary machine, only two is. Use `pow` or [exponentiation by squaring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625431/efficient-way-to-compute-pq-exponentiation-where-q-is-an-integer/5625446#5625446).

Comment: Yes. You're right! 10 is a special number in our everyday life, and in elementary school math class, but not in computer world.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no fast and efficient way to calculate it using IEEE 754 floating point representation. The fastest way to get the result is to build a table for every value of `m` that you care about, and then just perform a lookup.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with your suggestion to build a lookup table for a reasonable (not too big) m exponent.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a fast and efficient way to do it then I'm sure your CPU supports it, unless you're running on an embedded system in which case I'd *hope* that the pow(...) implementation is well written.

10 is special to us as most of us have ten fingers.  Computers only have two digits, so 2 is special to them.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use lookup table there cant be more than 1000 floats and especially if m is integer.

Answer (score 0):

IEEE 754 specifies a bunch of floating-point formats. Those that are in widespread use are binary, which means that base 10 isn't in any way special. This is contrary to your assumption that "10 is also a special base".

Interestingly, IEEE 754-2008 does add decimal floating-point formats ([`decimal32`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format) and friends). However, I'm yet to come across hardware implementations of those.

In any case, you shouldn't be micro-optimizing your code before you've profiled it and established that this is indeed the bottleneck.

Comment: Thye decimal floating point stuff is IBM's stuff; you'd find it on their mainframes.

Answer (score 0):

If you could operate with log n instead of n for a significant time, you could save time because instead of

```
n = pow(10*n,-m)
```

you now have to calculate (using the definition l = log10(n))

```
l = -m*(l+1)
```

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you for your attention. I don't fully understand you solution to my question. I want to evaluate the value x = n * pow(10, -m). So, further suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just some more ideas which may lead you to further solutions...

1. If you are interested in
   optimization on algorithm level you
   might look for a parallelized
   approach.
2. You may speed up on
   system/archtectural level on using Ipp
   (for Intel Processors), or e.g. AMD
   Core Math Library (ACML) for AMD
3. To use the power of your graphics
   card may be another way (e.g. CUDA for NVIDEA cards)
4. I think it's also worth to look at
   OpenCL

Comment: Dear Uhli, Thank you for your kind suggestions. The edge-cutting techs such as parallel compuattion, Intel/LPP, CUDA and OPenCl, as you mentioned here, will be bound to improve the performance of the coputatioal-extensive applications.